# Python doesn't dump core files

Tags: linux, python, signal, core

I have a problem where a Python process is hitting a segmentation fault but not producing a core file.

The following is a toy example that does not produce a core file on the following distros:

- Ubuntu 12.10
- Fedora 18

but does produce core files on the following distros:

- Scientific Linux 6
- Mac OS X

The reproduction:

```
$ python -c 'import time; time.sleep(120)'&    
$ kill -abrt $!   [1]+   
Aborted                 python -c 'import time; time.sleep(120)'  
$ ls core*   ls: cannot access core*: No such file or directory
```

However, if I send a similar signal to a `sleep` instance I do get a core file:

```
$ sleep 120 &  
$ kill -abrt $!  
[1]+  Aborted                 (core dumped) sleep 120  
$ ls core*  
core.8603
```

On my Fedora 18 box, here is my `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern   
core
```

And I've set the following:

```
$ ulimit -c  
unlimited
```

This is reproducible regardless of whether the `abrtd` service is running or not.

I'm pretty sure I've missed some basic configuration, but I don't know what. Thanks!

**EDIT**: This may be solvable by running:

```
$ echo 1 >/proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable
```

Comment: Is **core** a program on your system? What have you tried? Which of these has not solved your problem? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport , http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-497562.html , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833218/coredumpdirectory-isnt-working-on-ubuntu-getting-segmentation-fault-in-apache2

Comment: Did you try setting `suid_dumpable` to `1`? (only root can do that)

Comment: Please try following: `ls -lL $(which python) ; python -c 'import time; time.sleep(5)' & grep core /proc/$!/limits ; ls -ld "$(readlink /proc/$!/cwd)" ; grep ^Sig /proc/$!/status ; kill $!` The sequence will **1.** list the Python binary to check if it is not suid; **2.** list actual core limit of the process to check if it did not change; **3.** list the working directory of the process to check if it is writeable by the user; **4.** list signal masks of the process - please check if the `SIGABRT` (6) showing as `0000000000000020` is not blocked `SigBlk`, ignored `SigIgn` or caught `SigCgt`.

Comment: Although not directly related to the above example, if your python process happens to use the "daemon" module to put itself in the background that defaults to explicitly turning *off* core dumps.  You need to set prevent_core=False in the DaemonContext to override that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
$ echo 1 >/proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable
```

(or the equivalent in /etc/sysctl.conf to persist the change across reboots)

## longer

In my scenario I was using `setcap` to set certain capabilities on my Python process, to e.g. allow the use of raw sockets without having to be root. With this enabled you need to be root to get a core dump, or use the above command to explicitly tell the kernel it's OK for non-root users to get core dumps that they themselves can access.

(setting 2 would still enable core dumps in this situation but the said core dumps would only be accessible by the root user).